# Calculating Exponentially Weighted Moving Average in Snowflake using Snowpark

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table containing the monthly revenues of a bunch of assets in the following table schema:

```
ASSET_ID | MONTH | REVENUE
```

For each ASSET_ID, I want to calculate the rolling exponentially weighted moving average of revenues. I am currently using Snowpark but unable to figure out how to create the EWMA function. So far, I have:

```
def ewma(col, alpha):
  pass

alpha = 0.9
w = Window.partition_by("ASSET_ID").order_by("MONTH").rows_between(Window.UNBOUNDED_PRECEDING, Window.CURRENT_ROW - 1)
window = rev_df.select(col('ASSET_ID'), ewma(col('REVENUE'), alpha)).over(w)
```

Answer (score -1):

**How to write the function in python?**
Check out [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html), it has a built in `DataFrame.ewm()`.

**How to put a function in Snowpark?**
Read [the docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-udfs), it's not fun.

Specifically, for this application, I would use a [Vectorized Python UDF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-batch). There are very simple examples doing simple addition. In your case, the function should be simple enough that you can almost mirror these examples in here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to stay within the Snowpark library as much as possible. I understand Pandas would make it a lot easier.